# Ruby: JSON.parse with escaped backslash

Tags: ruby, json, escaping

I have a a JSON-encoded Array which looks like this (note: this is in a file, not the contents of a string): `["Company\\","NN","Company\\"]`. Is this invalid JSON? It contains an escaped `\` character and looks right to me. However:

```
a = '["Company\\","NN","Company\\"]'
 => "[\"Company\\\",\"NN\",\"Company\\\"]" 
JSON.parse a
JSON::ParserError: 387: unexpected token at 'NN","Company\"]'
from /Users/nneubauer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
from /Users/nneubauer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
from (irb):11
from /Users/nneubauer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Interestingly:

```
puts a
["Company\","NN","Company\"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's a difference between reading that sequence of bytes from  a file, and putting it in your Ruby code literally.

When you use `'` as the string delimiter in Ruby code, it still interprets `\\` as an escape sequence.  So you get a string with the value of `["Company\","NN","Company\"]`.

Then the JSON parser gets it. It sees the starting `[`, and then looks for a string. It interprets the `\"` sequence as an escape, so the first string it sees has a value of `Company\",`. It then expects to see a comma - but sees `NN` instead and throws up:

```
1.9.3-p194 :009 > a = '["Company\\","NN","Company\\"]'
 => "[\"Company\\\",\"NN\",\"Company\\\"]" 
1.9.3-p194 :010 > puts a
["Company\","NN","Company\"]
 => nil 
1.9.3-p194 :011 > JSON.parse(a)
JSON::ParserError: 387: unexpected token at 'NN","Company\"]'
```

But if I read that byte sequence from a file using `gets`, then the value ends up being `["Company\\","NN","Company\\"]`. This can be parsed as JSON - the `\\` is interpreted by JSON, then it sees the `"` and closes the first string in the array properly.

```
1.9.3-p194 :012 > b = gets
["Company\\","NN","Company\\"]
 => "[\"Company\\\\\",\"NN\",\"Company\\\\\"]\n" 
1.9.3-p194 :013 > puts b
["Company\\","NN","Company\\"]
 => nil 
1.9.3-p194 :014 > JSON.parse b
 => ["Company\\", "NN", "Company\\"] 
1.9.3-p194 :015 > JSON.parse(b).length
 => 3
```

So, what are you doing wrong? Cutting and pasting from a data file into source code. :)

Comment: Well, actually I'm reading this from a file, just wanted to debug the problem but didn't think of using `gets` for input. Thanks for the quick reply!